# How to overcome save data in table same time by two users

Tags: database, postgresql

I am implementing a seat booking application. I have a problem. There is a `booking` table. If two users try to book a same seat exact same time it will be a problem. How can I overcome this problem. I am using Java 8 and PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 1):

A database system is designed to handle concurrent queries like in your situation by itself.
You however need to make sure, that a seat can only be booked once.

Solution #1 If you insert a new entry in the booking table for each booked seat

```
INSERT INTO booking (booking_id, seat_id, customer_id) 
SELECT ?,?,?
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT seat_id FROM booking WHERE seat_id=?)
```

This solution will check if there is already a booking entry in the database with the seat_id you are trying to book. This can be also achieved by putting an unique constraint on the seat_id attribute in your table. However in this case your query will fail with an error - since the unique constraint is violated when inserting a duplicated value - while in the solution above the query will execute sucessfully and just not insert any value. This solution is prefered.

Solution #2 If you have one row for every seat in your database and just need to update if its booked

```
UPDATE booking
SET booking_id=?, booked=true
WHERE seat_id=? AND booked = false
```

Depending on your JDBC library you are able to replace the ? with your real values.

The database system will handle concurrent queries and only allow one query to pass.

Comment: If the first INSERT is run by two transactions at the same  time, you still wind up with two bookings on the same seat. You **have** to have a unique constraint in order to avoid that.

Comment: @Kylro is database handling concurrent queries that done in exact same time same seat?